# Which type of SSL certificate is required for use with Paypal Pro?

Tags: ssl, paypal

New to Paypal Pro. I'm processing encrypted credit cards through my shopping cart to Paypal Pro via API, ***not saving any card information***.

This is the information that I see on my certificate:

```
Certificate Type : Comodo Positive SSL 2048 bit
Protocol : TLS 1.2
Key Exchange : ECDHE_RSA
Cipher Suite : AES_128_GCM
```

The reason I'm asking is because I have been researching this and the internet is flooded with biased information that claims "EV SSL is essential for eCommerce."

I don't believe this to be true, considering what I've observed with the websites I've recently entered my card number into.

Comment: have you look at paypal's docs? for $20 a year you can buy one of their recommendations and move on. Probably a lot less than what you have spent during your research. If you must have a specific answer then may need to do more digging: https://www.paypal.com/sg/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=xpt/Marketing/merchant/CompatibleSSLCertPartner-outside

Comment: Yes, I have looked at them. They don't seem to specify, unless I'm missing something. From your link: `In providing this list, PayPal does not in any way endorse or make any representations regarding any of these vendors or their products, nor do we guarantee that all functionality for our services is compatible with the listed SSL certificates. We recommend you contact the vendor directly with all questions and issues regarding compatibility with our services.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any SSL certificate signed by a recognized CA will be sufficient. Even a free [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) certificate will work just fine.

The **only** purpose of an EV certificate is to make your company name show up in the URL bar of a web browser. EV certificates don't authenticate or encrypt your data any differently than other SSL certificates, and nothing that I'm aware of requires them for server-to-server communications.

Comment: Well, I know from shopping that EV SSL requires more identity verification, but yeah, you're right they are functionally the same.